# Ionic 4 how to login facebook with aws cognito session?

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, ionic-framework, amazon-cognito

I wrote this code which logs me in with facebook, but there is one problem, i need session token with cognito to work and I don't know how to get it.

```
facebookSignin(){
    // Login with permissions
   this.fb.login(['public_profile', 'email'])
   .then((loginres: FacebookLoginResponse) => {
     // The connection was successful
     if (loginres.status === 'connected') {
       // Get user infos from the API
       this.fb.api('/me?fields=name,gender,birthday,email', [])
         .then((profileres: any) => {
         let user =  {
            username  : profileres.name,
            password  : '',
            preferred_username : profileres.name,
              email            : profileres.email,
              phone_number      : profileres.phone_number,
              given_name       : profileres.name,
              family_name        : profileres.family_name,
              locale         : '',
              role        : 'sellers',
          }

          console.log('Uploading info....');

          this.amplify.setAuthState({state: 'fbLogin', user});
         });
     } else { // An error occurred while loging-in
       console.log('An error occurred...');
     }
   })
  }
```

This code logs me in to facebook with all the data, but then I get error from this code which cheks for the session :

```
getSession(authState){
const idTokenPayload = authState.getSignInUserSession().getIdToken().decodePayload();

....
}
```

> getSignInUserSession() is not a function;

Answer (score 0):

Cognito has two distinct resources, a User-Pool and an Identity-Pool. The design of these two seems somewhat unintuitive particularly in the context of the Federated authentication scenario we are considering. To further muddy the water it’s possible to authenticate against a User-Pool using a federated identify such as facebook, but only possible to do this through web pages and native apps and not ionic apps.

Cognition user-pools support Federated Authentication; but only from the AWS hosted pages. It is not (at time of writing) possible to directly authenticate with a Cognito User pool from a provider token. This is a pretty stark limitation, which means that unless we want to launch the AWS hosted Cognito pages – we are not able to user User-Pools in the scenario I presented.

Instead we need to use a Cognito Identity Pool to authenticate from a Facebook token. To achieve this we login onto Facebook using the client sdk, and then authenticate against the Cognito user-pool using Auth.federatedSignIn()

The draw-back of this is that we are unable to benefit from the functionality of Cognito user pools.

Direct authentication against an AppSync API
Store user information in the User pool
Please find below article.

[using-ionic-with-aws-amplify-facebook-authentication](https://martincroker.wordpress.com/2019/07/09/using-ionic-with-aws-amplify-facebook-authentication/)